# Percent comparison

Tags: percentages

I have a frequency list of words. This list was generated using 1,000,000 words. I want to compare how much more word 1 occurs compared to word 2.

For example,

The word "he" shows up 20000 times
The word "she" shows up 6000 times

What percent does the word he occur compared to she. In other words,

"He" occurs xx% more than the word "she"

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The ratio of one word to another has nothing to do with the $1,000,000$. are you asking for the difference in the percent, or just the ratio of one to the other?

Comment: @Andres Mejia the ratio from one to the other. It just didn't seem correct to me to divide by word1 over word2. Just one of those times where you look at a word and you are not sure if it's spelled correctly or not

Comment: Oh, okay! Well, I hope the answer is clear then. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

just take numbers of "he" divide it by the number of "she" then multiple the result by 100:
let
$n1$ is how much word1 showup
$n2$ is how much word2 showup
then the percentage $p$ is:

$p=\frac{n1}{n2} \cdot 100$

Comment: That's what I figured, but it just didn't seem correct. Thanks

Comment: You should define what is correct.